# Null data from Firebase Realtime Database Rules Simulator

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Showing null data for allowed reads on Firebase Realtime Database Rules Simulator?

I was expecting batman!

Data

```
{
  "users" : {
    "myuser" : "batman"
  }
}
```

Revised Data with node

```
{
  "users" : {
    "TnTz5ZgDoDSu68sPWIlnCseYjsZ2" : {
      "name" : "batman"
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Screen capture with rules and details of allowed read]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is showing to you is the correct expected behavior. The firebase realtime database location you wrote concerns nodes, not fields. Since `myuser` is a field and there is no node under `users` with the name `myuser` it returns null.

---

**Edit 1**

I just tested it myself and I get the same result. I asked a colleague, he said it has nothing to do with nodes/fields but the data field in the simulation is for what you are sending to the database not for what you are retrieving from it.

Comment: Hi thx Chris, but still confused.  For revised data with node (in OP above), I still get only null from locations I simulate reading.  I've tried /users ... /users/TnTz5ZgDoDSu68sPWIlnCseYjsZ2 ... /users/TnTz5ZgDoDSu68sPWIlnCseYjsZ2/name etc.

Comment: Ah, right you are!  The data in the Simulation results details is what is being sent in 'set' and 'update' simulation types, not what is retrieved in 'read' simulations. thx again!